# Client Credentials flow with AAD B2C

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a SPA React app with a NetCore API backend. This api is also used by another application.

I want to authenticate and authorize the SPA users using AAD B2C and the second app using the client credential flow. I understand that client credential flow is not supported by B2C. And I read that to achieve that I'd need to register the api again in Active Directory (non-B2C) as well as the client app and configure that using normal AD.

That will leave me with SPA and API registered as apps in B2C and API and client app in normal non-B2C.

IF.... all that is correct, how do I make the API validate both different types of clients? Authorizing users from B2C and client app through client credentials flow against AD non-B2C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For authorizing users from B2C, you just need to refer to this document: [Tutorial: Grant access to an ASP.NET web API using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=applications).

Your main concerns is for client credentials flow against AD non-B2C.

I have a test and the steps are the same as in the normal AD:

I registered a web API application in Azure AD B2C. Add an appRole in its `manifest.xml`.

```
"appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "Writers Have the ability to create tasks.",
            "displayName": "Writer",
            "id": "d1c2ade8-98f8-45fd-aa4a-6d06b947c66f",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Writer"
        }
    ]
```

Then I registered a web App application in normal AD. Add the API permission to it.

[image]

Use client credentials flow to acquire the access token.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, I believe I need to use the App Registrations (Preview) to create the API app, right? Because if I use the non-preview one it doesn't allow me to see or edit a manifest. 
I believe the App Registrations (Preview) shows the same apps that are created in the non-B2C AD, so it might be the same(?)

Comment: @MartínLaRosa If you use the non-preview one to create the API app, you will also be able to find it in App Registrations (Preview) and you can edit its manifest. (by clicking on "All applications") The apps registered in Azure AD and Azure AD B2C can be used for both of them. So apart from some special apps (eg. b2c-extensions-app), the two are the same.

Comment: Thanks very much, now it makes a bit more sennse.
Does the id in the app role mean anything? Is there something I have to consider when setting it up?

Comment: @MartínLaRosa You will need the id of app role if you are using API or SDK to assign users or groups to the app role. So,  just make sure it's a unique GUID.